# access to javascript var from actionlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my page I have the following script:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var needToConfirm = true;

    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

    function confirmExit() {
        if (needToConfirm) {
            return "You have attempted to leave this page. " +
                "If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost." +
                " Do you wish to proceed?";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am able to set the needToConfirm value in a button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="_submitButton" onclick="needToConfirm = false"/>
```

I want to know if there's a similar way to do this in an actionLink like this one:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove this item", "RemoveItemEdit", new
                            {
                                @_cardID = Model.mPackToEdit.mListCardPack[i].mCard.mMasterCard.mCardID,
                                needToConfirm = false
                            })
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of `ActionLink` is the route values. You need to put the `needtoconfirm` in the fourth parameter - `htmlAttributes`. Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Remove this item", 
    "RemoveItemEdit", 
    new { @_cardID = Model.mPackToEdit.mListCardPack[i].mCard.mMasterCard.mCardID },
    new { "onclick" = "needToConfirm = false" })
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of `Html.ActionLink`  that you are currently using is setting the **route values**.  You want to set the **html values**.

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove this item", "RemoveItemEdit", 
    new { 
        _cardID = Model.mPackToEdit.mListCardPack[i].mCard.mMasterCard.mCardID
    },
    new { 
        needToConfirm = false
    });
```

Comment: Just FYI, this would create a parameter called `needtoconfirm`, not a `onclick` param setting the value.